# pdf format cutting the last 4 columns of a table in BIRT 4.5 (Auto Layout)

Tags: birt, birt-emitter

Using BIRT 4.5.

I have a table with 16 columns and so it spreads out on the viewer. I am using Auto Layout and not Fixed Layout to accommodate all 16 columns.

When I download the Pdf version of report from BIRT Viewer the report is cutting the columns on the right of the table(4-5 columns).

I did some research and it said to use Fixed layout but it is not possible in the scenario.

I saw one post here which said something like this -  "InterfaceIPDFRender, set your PAGE_OVERFLOW = FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE and that should do it"

What does the above line mean? Is it that I need to make changes in jar of library and then recompile the code of BIRT VIEWER? Can someone please help on this.

Regards,
Ajay B

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the Type pf Master page to US Super B and change the width of Master page. This allows pdf to accommodate the whole table.

Regards,
Ajay B